# Using sort_values, how can I get the maximum value from a list of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I found the code but I can't understand the logic behind it. the iloc[0] gives me the country name which has the maximum value from the column.

`sort_values(by='% Renewable', ascending=False).iloc[0]`

Comment: try with df.max() ?

Comment: max doesn't work. The code that I've given works fine. But I don't understand the logic.

Comment: .iloc[0] gives you the first row in the sorted column. This is the maximum value since its been sorted in a descending manner. You could do this too if you want: `sort_values(by='% Renewable', ascending=True).iloc[-1]`  Check out the docs from pandas if you want more info on iloc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html

Comment: ```sort_values``` with ```ascending=False``` gets the rows with the highest count based on ```% Renewable```. iloc[0] simply gets you the first row, which is also the row with the highest count.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt responses. I understand now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: KaiserAzad: **`max()` definitely does work, see my answer.** The point is to slice only your column-of-interest first, then invoke its `max()` method. There was no need to sort the entire dataframe using `.sort_values` if you only wanted to find the max of one column... you could still do that, but it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

- **BAD:** `df.sort_values(by='% Renewable', ...)` **sorts the entire pandas dataframe, not just your column-of-interest**
- **GOOD: you only want the max in that one column, so simply slice that column and do:** `df['% Renewable'].max()`

  - [`pd.Series.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) is a vectorized pandas operation on a Series. in particular, `skipna=True` arg default prevents you getting NaNs for the max, if there are any NaNs present in that column.

Notes:

- `You don't need iloc[0]`, which just slices the top row of a dataframe. Or equivalently, `head(1)`.
- this is all neglecting that there could be more than one row containing the max value